# R subsetting data frame column rows with dynamic values

Tags: r, subset, dynamic-values

I have data frame named `dcWCTOneSubTotal` which has column `T1Description` having multiple values .

How to pass each value after storing this in a variable like descriptionName.
It returns null if i pass value as `T1Description=='descriptionName'` to subset function.

It returns rows if i pass value as `T1Description=="abc"`  or `T1Description=="xyz"` to subset function.

I want to call this

```
bar.Chart.D.F.1 <- subset(dcWCTOneSubTotal ,  T1Description=='descriptionName')
```

inside function so that I can have different subsets each time for different T1Description column.

Comment: Is `descriptionName` a variable? Did you try `bar.Chart.D.F.1 <- subset(dcWCTOneSubTotal, T1Description==descriptionName)`?

Comment: `descriptionName` (no quotes) is an object (variable), that might have a value like `2` or `"The Roman Empire"`. `"descriptionName"` (with quotes) is just the literal text "descriptionName". Its value is always `"descriptionName"`, just like `2`'s value is always `2`.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments - just omit the quotes:

```
dcWCTOneSubTotal <- data.frame(T1Description = c("a","b","c","a","c","b"),
                               T2Description = 1:6, 
                               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dcWCTOneSubTotal
#   T1Description T2Description
# 1             a             1
# 2             b             2
# 3             c             3
# 4             a             4
# 5             c             5
# 6             b             6


sub = "a"
subset(dcWCTOneSubTotal, T1Description==sub)
#   T1Description T2Description
# 1             a             1
# 4             a             4

sub= "b"
subset(dcWCTOneSubTotal, T1Description==sub)
#   T1Description T2Description
# 2             b             2
# 6             b             6
```